Understanding sentences in sptenrand() in tensor_toolbox
When I try to figure out the meaning of the codes of the sptenrand() function to write a function to create a sparse tensor with a different distribution, I am stacked in the following two steps:

subs = [];
cnt = 0;
while (size(subs,1) < nz) && (cnt < 10)%nz is the number of nonzeros
subs = ceil( rand(nz, size(sz,2)) * diag(sz) );%sz is the size of the tensor
subs = unique(subs, 'rows');
cnt = cnt + 1;
end


why the condition for cnt is 10?
what's the meaning for the operations on subs?

The second step is at

nz = min(nz, size(subs,1));
subs = subs(1:nz,:);
vals = rand(nz,1);
then sptenrand() uses sptensor(subs,vals,sz) to create tensor, I understand how vals is generated but I am confused about the construction of subs.

I am very appreciate for the help for answering the questions!

I think you should ask this on StackOverflow instead. That's the forum that deals with coding-related questions.
